# Convert a txt file to Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>> C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file and I need to put all even lines to Dictionary Key and all even lines to Dictionary Value. What is the best solution to my problem?

Text File:

```
[1 (832, 315, title1)]
[2 (232, 115, title2)]
[3 (432, 215, title3)]
[4 (132, 315, title4)]
[5 (932, 415, title5)]
```

I have this solution but it was broke;

```
private Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>> textToDictionary()
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines("mypath");

            return lines
                .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                .GroupBy(item => Convert.ToInt32(item[0]))
                .ToDictionary(groupValues => groupValues.Key, groupValues => groupValues.ToDictionary(item => item[1], item => Convert.ToDouble(item[2])));
        }
```

Comment: "it was broke" - tell us *why* it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the string sequentially eating up to given tokens in your string `[`,`(`,`,`.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = @"[1 (832, 315, title1)]
[2 (232, 115, title2)]
[3 (432, 215, title3)]
[4 (132, 315, title4)]
[5 (932, 415, title5)]
";
        TextToDictionary(input.AsSpan());
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>> TextToDictionary(ReadOnlySpan<char> span)
    {
        var output = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, string>>();

        while (span.Length > 0)
        {
            span = EatUntilToken(span, "[");
            span = ConsumeToAndEatToken(span, "(", out var int1);
            span = ConsumeToAndEatToken(span, ",", out var double1);
            span = ConsumeToAndEatToken(span, ",", out var double2);
            span = ConsumeToAndEatToken(span, ")", out var string1);
            span = EatUntilToken(span, Environment.NewLine);

            output.Add(int.Parse(int1), Tuple.Create(double.Parse(double1), double.Parse(double2), string1.ToString()));
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static ReadOnlySpan<char> ConsumeToAndEatToken(ReadOnlySpan<char> instruction, string token, out ReadOnlySpan<char> value)
    {
        var indexOf = instruction.IndexOf(token);
        if (indexOf < 0)
            throw new Exception($"String {instruction.ToString()} does not contain the expected token {token}");

        value = instruction[..(indexOf)];
        return instruction[(indexOf + token.Length)..];
    }

    private static ReadOnlySpan<char> EatUntilToken(ReadOnlySpan<char> instruction, string token)
    {
        var indexOf = instruction.IndexOf(token);
        if (indexOf < 0)
            throw new Exception($"String {instruction.ToString()} does not contain the expected token {token}");

        return instruction[(indexOf + token.Length)..];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first line, `item[0]` is `[1` and `item[2]` is `315,` which cannot be converted to int or double respectively as they contain additional characters (`[` and `,`). It is not sufficient to just use `Split(' ')`, you have to further treat the data.

Fix it using:

```cs
int.Parse(item[0].TrimStart('['))
double.Parse(item[2].TrimEnd(','))
```

Also, `item[1]` that you use as the key for your inner dictionary is `(832` for the first line. Probably you only want `832` which you can get using:

```cs
item[1].TrimStart("(");
```

Comment: the problem was Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, double, string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Tuple<double, double, string>>'